# Check if product is in specific category?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to check if a product is located in a specific category and change the label of add to cart button in product-list.tpl

In this case i would like to display "Read more here" instead of "Add to cart" if product is located in category id 14.

Right now all products from category 14 is getting "Add to cart"

I'm running 1.6.0.11

```
{assign var='associated' value=0}                
    {foreach Product::getProductCategories($smarty.get.id_product) as $category}
       {if in_array($category, 14)}
          {assign var='associated' value=1}
       {/if}
 {/foreach}
{if $associated==1}
  {l s='Read more here'}
{else}
  {l s='Add to cart'}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
{assign cat14 [['id_category' => 14]]}
{if Product::idIsOnCategoryId($smarty.get.id_product, $cat14)}
    {l s='Read more here'}
{else}
    {l s='Add to cart'}
{/if}
```

Comment: this works on PS 1.6.1.5 :-) In product.tpl, `$product->id` is even shorter :-) ,

Answer (score 0):

When i have to do something similar i just set the catalog mode on for one (or more) categories:

(I add this just after the foreach loop in product-list.tpl)

```
{assign findcat [['id_category' => 14], ['id_category' => 33]]}
{if Product::idIsOnCategoryId($product.id_product, $findcat)}
    {assign var="PS_CATALOG_MODE" value="true"}
{/if}
```

And if you need to hide selling options in product page add this at the beginning (product.tpl):

```
{assign cat15 [['id_category' => 15], ['id_category' => 17], ['id_category' => 27], ['id_category' => 29], ['id_category' => 30], ['id_category' => 31]]}
{if Product::idIsOnCategoryId($product->id, $cat15)}
    {assign var="PS_CATALOG_MODE" value="true"}
{/if}
```